# Showing audio metadata on phone block screen?

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, html5-audio

I have an html5 audio player on my page that streams from my icecast server, all working OK. However, when people block their phone there's no metadata, only the play button that iOS/Android offers.

Is there a way to show something like 'Glaciar's livestream', like when the Spotify app shows the song's title and artist? I'm using PHP and Javascript apart from HTML and CSS.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Media Session API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Session_API) to customize what's been shown on the lock screen.

<strike>But it is not supported by Safari which means you can't use it to customize the lock screen on an iOS device.</strike>

According to [Can I use...](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_mediasession) it can now be used in every major browser.

Comment: Looks like you now can...
https://caniuse.com/?search=Media%20Session%20API

Comment: Thanks Shano for letting me know. I will update the answer.

Comment: I've been playing with it a little bit, it seems very inconsistent or else I'm doing something wrong. Most of the time the lock screen/overlay says "not playing" but sometimes picks up the audio playing from my browser (where I'm running an app that sets the media session metadata)

Comment: I guess it would have been too good to be true. :-(

Answer (score 1):

I just came along the same issue. Our Webapp would not display anything on the lock screen even though audio was playing. This is what I just found out:

We are setting up an `new Audio()` element in javascript - within the user interaction we call `audio.load()`. Then we wait for the `canplay` event to fire and with that event handler, we call `audio.play()`. When the phone now gets locked, there is nothing shown on the lock screen.

However, when we add `audio.play()` directly after `audio.load()`, so it is called within the same user interaction, everything shows up fine on the lock screen. So it seems like, it matters if `audio.play()` is called within a user interaction.

Some more background in case someone wonders why we are not calling play within the user interaction: We usually use an audio context (that is unlocked within a user interaction) and just started to fall back to an audio element, due to numerous audio related bugs in safari.